# MongoDB Connection Management

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the standard .net driver (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial) and am interested to know how we can use the driver to manage connections in a similar way to how we do on our SQL DB's.

Here is how we connect to our SQL DB

```
public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
        {
            var ConnectionStrO = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_ConnectionStringName];
            var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrO.ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            return connection;  
        }
```

Then to use that connection at any point in the app, we simply call

```
using(var CurConnection = Database.GetOpenConnection())
{

    //Use connection here.

}
```

Are there any example of how we can do a similar thing with MongoDB and manage the connection like above?

Or any other suggestions on managing connections with the MongoDb driver?

Comment: I dont like how u work with sql server connection. it shouldn't be a static class/method but a dependency to whoever needs a connection. For mongodb, driver handles connection pool internally.

Comment: @DarthVader The mongo example posted below, looks identical to what we do with SQL Server. Care to explain whats wrong with how we use SQL Connection?

Comment: i told already. it shouldn't be a static class/method but a dependency to whoever needs a connection. and using a static method/class, you will have a hidden side effect somewhere in your code. look at the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458415/repository-unit-of-work-pattern-for-entity-framework-using-dependency-injectio

Comment: that s just one way of doing . u just need some abstraction and clear design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-TheC%23Driver

```
public static function MongoServer GetConnection() {
    var url = MongoUrl.Create(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_ConnectionStringName]);
    var server = MongoServer.Create(url);
    return server;
}
```

Comment: No idea how I missed that! Thanks.