# EF 5 is performing LEFT OUTER JOIN unnecessarily on simple Select

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Performing:

```
using (var DB = new SiteEntities())
{
  var test = DB.All<AssessmentItem>();
}
```

Results in this SQL query, why is a join being performed?! I did not state to query the Products table at all and it is causing me issues with duplicate data. I have never seen this behaviour.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
[Extent1].[ImageFileName] AS [ImageFileName], 
[Extent1].[ReplacementCost] AS [ReplacementCost], 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1]
FROM  [dbo].[AssessmentItems] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[AssessmentItemID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[AssessmentItemID])
```

This is my AssessmentItem.cs generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class AssessmentItem
{
    public AssessmentItem()
    {
        this.AssessmentItemAttributeMappings = new HashSet<AssessmentItemAttributeMapping>();
        this.CustomerAssessmentItems = new HashSet<CustomerAssessmentItem>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ReplacementCost { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssessmentItemAttributeMapping> AssessmentItemAttributeMappings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerAssessmentItem> CustomerAssessmentItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

```
using (var DB = new SiteEntities())
{
  var test = DB.All<AssessmentItem>()
      .Select(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.Name
        });
}
```

Products the correct SQL query, there must be some sort of funky inference going on in the background. I would still like to know if anyone has any ideas as to why.

Comment: I think you have navigation property `Products` in your `AssessmentItem`.

Comment: Only a singular `virtual Product` Hamlet, code sample added.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out what the darn issue was, it appears I had setup `AssessmentItem<>Product` relationship as a 1-1 relationship in EF. As a byproduct of this, there was no AssessmentItemID INT foreign key on the Products table any more, as removing it was suggested by the instructions I followed and wouldn't work without it removed, it seems that was the issue, as when I went to save a `Product` record which I hadn't done until now, it complained about the missing FK. Figured both issues were related, re-adding the Products table to the EF designer surface fixed it.

Thanks guys for being patient with me. I really think EF should make it easier to perform 1-1 relationships, I'm going to have to simply do a `.Single()` now every time I wish to access this. :(

Answer (score 0):

`DbSet.All` is typically used to test whether items of a sequence satisfy a particular predicate .. in your case you are not providing any predicate and it seems to be doing an eager load.

In your case it expects a `Func<AssessmentItem, bool>` as the predicate

If you simply want all the items why not simply say.

```
DB.AssessmentItems;
```

Comment: It's not that easy, as this was cut down for simplicity, but it actually runs through a generic data layer, where an Expression can be passed through. I have made an update to the question, with a small win.

Comment: @GONeale I'm not sure why you are using DB.All .. please could you explain that? At the moment you are only projecting it to a select. Is All an extension method you've defined somewhere or the generic Linq All extension method?

Comment: Ok, sorry that was just the quickest way I found to convert my more long-winded code. I have basically a 'repository' interface for EF connectivity, called SiteEFSession, within it I have this method:
`public IQueryable<T> All<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class
{ return _context.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsQueryable(); }`, so you can do something like `session.All<AssessmentItem>()` and it returns all items. or `session.All<AssessmentItem>(x => x.ID > 5)` to return all where ID>5. etc.

Comment: @GONeale Maybe you could paste the method if it isn't too long . that's the only way to know whats going on there.

Comment: It actually follows a well known pattern I believe, I originally saw Rob Conery use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458415/repository-unit-of-work-pattern-for-entity-framework-using-dependency-injectio

Comment: If i may add, you don't need the AsQueryable() anymore .. Where() returns an IQueryable.

Comment: Ok thanks scartag. So all in all, I have no idea why it's still extending out into the Product lookup. But a specific select is working right now, and I need to move on. But still really want to leave this question open in hope to resolve the underlying issue for future tasks.